# Yii missingAction captcha when being called in modal

Tags: php, yii, captcha

So I have Yii-user and Yii-bootstrap. I want to load the registration form with a modal dialog when the user clicks something on the main page. I have loaded the class in the actions of all my controllers.

```
 $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BootModal', array('id'=>'logonDialog')); ?>
   <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
    <h3>Inscription ou Connexion</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span6"><?php
          $lmodel=new UserLogin;
          $this->renderPartial('application.modules.user.views.user.login',array('model'=>$lmodel,));
         ?></div>
         <div class="span6">
         <?
          $rmodel = new RegistrationForm;
          $rprofile=new Profile;
          $this->renderPartial('application.modules.user.views.user.registration',array('model'=>$rmodel,'profile'=>$rprofile));
         ?>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 <div class="modal-footer"></div>
<?php $this->endWidget();
```

The login form is working properly but the only problem with this is that there's no captcha on the registration form and I get an error in the logs:

```
2012/07/14 12:37:28 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:37:32 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:37:38 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:37:41 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:37:42 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:37:48 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:38:01 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:38:04 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:38:13 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:38:14 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (29)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:38:14 [warning] [application] Failed to set unsafe attribute "verifyCode" of "RegistrationForm".
in /home/something/protected/modules/user/controllers/RegistrationController.php (37)
in /home/something/public_html/test.php (15)
2012/07/14 12:44:56 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'Le système ne peut trouver l'action « captcha » demandée.' in /home/something/yii/framework/web/CController.php:484
Stack trace:
#0 /home/something/yii/framework/web/CController.php(271): CController->missingAction('captcha')
#1 /home/something/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(276): CController->run('captcha')
#2 /home/something/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(135): CWebApplication->runController('user/login/capt...')
#3 /home/something/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(162): CWebAp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use different scenario for multiple forms on the same model. Read about [yii scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/).

Also you need to [understand safe validation rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/).